# R Histogram dbplot count bars oriented sideways with default parameters

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, data-visualization

Can anyone help me figure out why the following code gives me a different plot than expected? I'm thinking I accidentally nuked some global option somewhere, but I can't figure out what. Note that the code produces frequency (count) bars on the wrong axis.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dbplot)
library(dplyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "2.3")
cars <- copy_to(sc, mtcars)
dbplot_histogram(cars, hp)
```

Here is the resulting plot on my system:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it might be the default for dbplot_histogram. I get the same thing when running your code, but it's not a global option issue as the geom_histogram works fine.

```
#horizontal
dbplot_histogram(mtcars, hp, bins = 30, binwidth = NULL)
```

`#vertical
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp)) + geom_histogram()`

[image]

Comment: There must be a bug somewhere, then, because the plot I am getting would be saying there are only 18 cars, which is not the case. I was originally trying to reproduce the first plot in [Ch. 4 of The R in Spark](https://therinspark.com/modeling.html#overview-1), but that is a little long for stack overflow.